# Odoo - Filter Many2one not by _rec_name

Tags: odoo

I would like to filter m2o field, but not by default name (_rec_name).

```
class LecturerWorkday(models.Model):
    _name = 'lecturer.workday'
    _rec_name = 'lecturer_id'
  
    name = fields.Selection([('sunday','Sunday'),('monday','Monday'),('tuesday','Tuesday'),
        ('wednesday','Wednesday'),('thursday','Thursday'),('friday','Friday'),('saturday','Saturday'),
    ], default='sunday',string="Workday", required=True)
    lecturer_id = fields.Many2one('school.lecturer', string="Lecturer Name", invisible=True)

class SchoolLecturer(models.Model):
    _name = 'school.lecturer'

     name = fields.Char(string="Lecturer Name", required=True)
     workday_id = fields.Many2one("lecturer.workday", string="Workday ID")

 class LecturerTimeoff(models.Model):
    _name = "lecturer.timeoff"

    lecturer = fields.Many2one('school.lecturer', string="Lecturer Name")
    day_m2o = fields.Many2one('lecturer.workday', string="Lecturer Workdays")
    reason  = fields.Char("Time off Reason")

    @api.onchange('lecturer')
       def get_lecturer_workday(self):
         day_obj = self.env['lecturer.workday'].search([('lecturer_id', '=', self.lecturer.id)]).mapped('name')
         day_list = []
            for rec in day_obj:
                day_list.append(rec)
                res = {}
                res['domain'] = {'day_m2o': [('name', '=', day_list)]}
                return res
                print (res)
```

My question are:

1. When I choose lecturer name, day_m2o should display the workday of selected lecturer name. I have been trying to compute it as above, but the result is still display lecturer name, instead of workday.
2. It seems that @api.onchange didn't update the result instantly whenever i clicked the new lecturer name who didn't have workday yet. How to fix this?

Thanks for your help